# can't have correct custom error bars after a sort in Excel?

Tags: excel

I have a problem with custom error bars in Excel.
If I have three values, 52, 34 and 48 and I do a barchart. I add custom error bars like this:

[Errorbars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZdpd.png)

So there they are correct. On the other hand, if I sort my data, the error bars do not follow, they remain in the same order as before the sort.

Do you have an idea that would allow me to have the correct error bars after the sort?

Answer (score 0):

You should not use array constant to define error bars, because there is no connection between these values and your data. Instead, you should place your errors in the sheet, in definition of error bars use a reference to this sheet and sort these errors with your data. Then you get proper results.
[image: Error Bars]

Comment: Ok yes, I had this idea in mind but I wanted to know if there is another solution. 
I will do that like that, thank you